# Realm java sort with multiple fields

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm sorting like this:

```
RealmResults<Show> shows = realm.where(Show.class).findAll();
shows.sort("venueTitle", RealmResults.SORT_ORDER_ASCENDING);
```

How can I sort by multiple properties? Adding another sort line just resets the order of the results entirely.

Comment: I would assume you could chain queries. I don't have exposure to `Realm` but by glancing at the API it seems it would be possible. I don't know if this is what you meant by "Adding another sort... just resets the order"

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately chaining sorts is not possible.

Comment: realm should indicate in the documentation that the `sort` is not stable. (which they don't)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like they just added this in 0.77. I was using 0.76. Here's the Github issue:
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/648

and here's the API reference:
http://realm.io/docs/java/0.77.0/api/

```
public void sort(java.lang.String[] fieldNames,
    boolean[] sortAscending)
```

Comment: was about to post a link of their forum where they talk about this being a feature they were working on!

Answer (score 13):

try below code

```
 public RealmResults getSortedList(Class aClass) {
        String []fieldNames={"field1","field2"};
        Sort sort[]={Sort.ASCENDING,Sort.ASCENDING};
        return realm.where(YourClass.class).findAllSorted(fieldNames,sort);
    }
```